# Link Colors for Visited and Non-Visited Links too Similar

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface

I have been browsing gamedev for a while and at first noticed that the color differences between a clicked link and a non-clicked link were rather similar.  I attributed this to my poor eyesight (currently being corrected with -7.25 and -6.25 glasses) and figured I would eventually get used to the similarity.  I have not been able to and I find it rather difficult.

Here is an image of how the site is rendered on my computer with Google Chrome:

[image: The first link is unclicked and has a brightish green color, whereas the second unclicked link is a slightly dark green.]

Now, I can tell the difference, but it sometimes takes a second look or to pause slightly longer when scanning through a list.

My suggestion would be to either choose a separate color or to improve the contrast/shade.  I am not much of a color person, so I can't make any specific recommendations.

Comment: It's not just you. My eyesight is just fine and sometimes I have to pause. I just don't mind doing so - it's not a big deal.

Comment: I have edited this to have the [tag:feature-request] tag instead of the [tag:bug] tag, as links are behaving perfectly correctly and as designed, you just want to improve them.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs, I couldn't quite figure out which was more appropriate, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could GDSE's low-visibility hyperlinks please be revisited and improved on main, meta and in chat?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2476/could-gdses-low-visibility-hyperlinks-please-be-revisited-and-improved-on-main)

Comment: Voting to close this as a duplicate of the meta where this got resolved for our record-keeping purposes.