# Could GDSE's low-visibility hyperlinks please be revisited and improved on main, meta and in chat?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, hyperlinks, meta

GDSE has a bunch of issues with its links having major perception issues across the board. **Could link colors on this site's main, meta, and chat please be revisited?** My request would be that our links should be clearly distinguishable from regular text in all three site areas, and preferably visited and unvisited links would be distinguishable from each other.

Some of these issues have sat reported for several years unactioned. On meta and chat they incur severe legibility issues, and that's for people with good eyesight and well-adjusted monitors.

- **Chat:** We can hardly see links at all. Reported in 2014: [Can we get a hyperlink style for chat that is less subtle?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1624/can-we-get-a-hyperlink-style-for-chat-that-is-less-subtle), [Link color in chat is too similar to normal text color](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2397/link-color-in-chat-is-too-similar-to-normal-text-color?noredirect=1). This is impactful enough that when I'm linking people to stuff in chat, I have now been making a habit of [pointing out](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19?m=37863887#37863887) there is actually a link there or [using link emoji](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38297878#38297878), so that they don't miss it.
- **Meta:** Visited and unvisited links have significant visibility issues. Visited links are a dark grey, which is hard to tell apart from the off-black regular text (these have a [**2.6:1** color contrast ratio](http://leaverou.github.io/contrast-ratio/#%23242729-on-%23666), which is poor at this font scale). Visited links aren't great either: that dark red only has a [**1.2:1** color contrast ratio](http://leaverou.github.io/contrast-ratio/#%23242729-on-%236c0000) versus regular text, which makes it an extremely difficult-to-detect colour difference.
- **Main:** Visited and unvisited links look practically the same. Reported in 2012: [Link Colors for Visited and Non-Visited Links too Similar](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/967/link-colors-for-visited-and-non-visited-links-too-similar). This is the only place we can at least actually clearly tell links apart from regular text.

Comment: We should not duplicate-close a meta question designed to shed light on an issue that has thus far received _no response_ one way or the other from SE developers, for quite the same reason as we won't be duplicate-closing [this](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/can-we-enable-mathjax-on-gdse-revisited) or any question that is about revisiting old policy decisions such as [this](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2293/generic-programming-questions-are-off-topic-period-right).

Answer (score 5):

As you may be able to see, the link colors on Meta.GameDevelopment have been updated. They have been reverted to the standard Meta link colors.

---

#### Update July 24, 2017

Chat and GD.SE link colors have been updated and will be updated once production builds out. Once production build, I'll update the post's status.

---

#### Update July 26, 2017

Production has been built out. I've updated the post's status.

Comment: I'm pretty happy with this change! Those are much more functional link colors, and they look just fine with our meta theme. (Grey goes with every color!)

Comment: Seeing the status-completed tag, I'll note that this bug report covers chat and main as well. Is the chat issue also being looked at separately?

Comment: @doppelgreener Sorry. It's been a busy few weeks and this fell off my radar. We'll take a look at it this week. I've updated the status to reflect the fact that we aren't finished with this post yet.

Comment: Thanks very much for checking back in and updating us. :)

Comment: We've just seen the update to link colors in chat. Thank you so much for updating that. :)