# Do/should we allow Emojis here?

Tags: discussion

I've come across [this post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/revisions/143104/1), which reads:

> What the possible codes?? Using Adobe flash CS6 AS 3.0 for tracing Game.. A-Z  , 1-100 & shapes.. By levels.. For kids. Hand game. Please help me...  I really need your help please..

Regardless of the overall quality of this post, since Emojis have been integrated in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Unicode_blocks), allowing them to be typed anywhere, should we allow them in the posts? Can they add value to posts or are they generally more a distraction and/or show a lack of ability to write proper questions/answers? Are they too chatty/forum-y?

Do we have a policy about this? Should we have one?

Comment: Embrace the emoji! 

Answer (score 14):

I don't think there's anything wrong with them when used sparingly, in essentially the same way we'd use old-fashioned ASCII smilies like ":)" and the like.

I don't think it's appropriate to replace every word that could be replaced with an emoji with one, nor do I think it's appropriate to "spam" them in use them excessively in a row, or after every sentence, et cetera.

Answer (score 12):

To me they generally read the same as [fluff text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions), I would treat them accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

Emojis are fine; they add some body language into our communications and sometimes (infrequently) that's *really* important. They also let us use symbols, and I've [used those before](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/142366/2698)  to what I feel is positive effect in punctuating a post. (Tangentially I've also been using the link emoji to make it clear where I'm linking to something [until our links get revised](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2476/2698) .)

The real problem there is, like [Pikalek points out](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2487/2698) , that text is [fluff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions) . Stack Exchange likes a high signal:noise ratio, and that applies to individual posts as well. All the formalities you might find at the start or end of a post (“Hi”, “thanks in advance”, “please help”, etc) are noise; remove them from the post with prejudice. Posts should be as close to 100% signal as possible, and it's almost always completely possible.

Would you rather read:

> Hi everyone! I'm new here, still figuring this site out. Anyway so my question is, how do I foo a sprocket? I'm having trouble. The documentation isn't any help! Please help me with this!!!
>
> Thanks in advance. Cheers, Doppelgreener.
>
> Edit: I get this error when I try to foo the sprocket: (...)

Or this?:

> How do I foo a sprocket? I'm having trouble and the documentation isn't any help.
>
> I get this error when I try to foo the sprocket: (...)

The first is a problem whether or not it's also littered with emojis; those just make it even worse. Having to read posts like the former over and over (along with bad spelling/grammar) is what drove me to be a prolific editor.

TLDR: Emojis aren't a problem here; fluff is; exterminate it so thoroughly it'd make Arnold Schwarzenegger impressed.

Answer (score 0):

In sparing use, emojis are OK. However, they should not be spammed or use inappropriately, unlike fluff, which should be banished.